# Crystal Reports: Link table from formula field

Tags: sql, hyperlink, crystal-reports, field, formula

I need to find out if I can link two unrelated tables together via a formula field in Crystal Reports. Can this be done? If not, I will need help figuring out a solution.

Details:

Table_A contains a string "comment" field. The comment field contains random words and a unique invoice number. I have created a formula field within crystal to split out the unique invoice number, so the data is now ready to be linked to Table_B via the unique number, if possible. I haven't found a way to proceed, and honestly I don't think it's possible.

In the case that it is not possible, I suppose I would need to pull the necessary data from Table_A, split out the invoice number, and create a temporary table prior to pulling the data and Table_B into Crystal, correct? While I have very basic SQL experience, I honestly have no idea how I would go about doing that. Any help would be appreciated.

I'm on Crystal XI and we use MAS 200 ERP 4.4

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly, no.

Options:

- use a subreport - one table in the main report, the other in the subreport; create a formula field to convert one of the field's value to match the other; link on this field
- create a SQL view that does the work; use the view instead of the two tables
- use a Command to link the two tables

Comment: Thanks! I'll give the subreport a shot. Would you be at all willing to go into a little more detail on the second two points? I would really appreciate it. I have no idea what you mean.